# Routing between templates not working for Angular UI

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here is my router.js

angular.module('app.routes', []).config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

```
$stateProvider.state('tabsController.dashboard', {
    url : '/page2',
    views : {
        'tab1' : {
            templateUrl : 'templates/dashboard.html',
            controller : 'dashboardCtrl'
        }
    }
}).state('tabsController.searchResults', {
    url : '/page1/page3',
    views : {
        'tab1' : {
            templateUrl : 'templates/searchResults.html',
            controller : 'searchResultsCtrl'
        }
    }

}).state('tabsController', {
    url : '/page1',
    abstract : true,
    templateUrl : 'templates/tabsController.html'
});

// if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/page1/page2');
```

});

Here is my routing template dashboard.html

```
<ion-content class="has-header" padding="true">

    <form class="list" name="myform">
        <label class="item item-input" name="Language"> <i class="icon ion-search placeholder-icon"></i>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Language" name="lang" ng-model="dashboardCtrl.localMovies.lang" ng-minlength=1 ng-disabled="myform.movie.$valid" required>
        </label>
        <span> OR </span>
        <label class="item item-input" name="Movie"> <i class="icon ion-search placeholder-icon"></i>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Name of Movie" name="movie" ng-model="dashboardCtrl.localMovies.movie" ng-minlength=1 ng-disabled="myform.lang.$valid" required>
        </label>
    </form>
    <a class="button button-positive button-block " href="#/page1/page3/">Search</a>
</ion-content>
```

SearchResult.html template is not loading when click search button. Please help me to find out issue

Comment: you didn't inject `ui.router`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.state('tabsController.searchResults', {
    url : '/page3',
    views : {
        'tab1' : {
            templateUrl : 'templates/searchResults.html',
            controller : 'searchResultsCtrl'
        }
    }

})
```

Child state will inherits url from parent state and adds `/page3` so `tabsController.searchResults` state's url will become `/page1/page3`

Comment: Thank you quick response. I changed url as "/page3" but still it is not working. Is there anything else missing ?

Comment: @Sara inject ui.router

Answer (score 0):

I think you have made a url mistake.
In here

```
state('tabsController.searchResults', {
    url : '/page1/page3',
    views : {
        'tab1' : {
            templateUrl : 'templates/searchResults.html',
            controller : 'searchResultsCtrl'
        }
    }
})
```

url should be like this:

```
url : '/page3'
```

Comment: Thank you quick response.  I changed url as "/page3" but still it is not working. Is there anything else missing ?

Comment: I'm sorry for the late response....
Why dont you try using ui-sref='tabsController.searchResults' instead of href